# svg text animation with delay

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

i want to implement something like this http://24ways.org/2013/animating-vectors-with-svg/ but i want each letter start draw after the finish of the previous. i dont know how to implement this with delay.

here is my code :

```
var init = function() {

path = new Array();
length = new Array();

for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
       path[i] = document.getElementById('path'+i);
       length = path[i].getTotalLength();
       path[i].style.transition = path[i].style.WebkitTransition = 'none';

       length[i] = length;
       path[i].style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
       path[i].style.strokeDashoffset = length;

       path[i].getBoundingClientRect();
       path[i].style.transition = path[i].style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';

       path[i].style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
    }
};

init();
```

in this example i have two letters 'sp' and i want 's' draw first and then when finish start the 'p' letter. in my example the two letters draw simultaneously. if someone could help me i would appreciate it.

here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/thLvLkq0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just making the animation start after a delay?

I forked your fiddle to make it work like that.

http://jsfiddle.net/pz19fL7h/

```
for(var i=1; i<3; i++) {
    init(i);
    (function(i) {
        window.setTimeout(function() { start(i, duration); }, (i-1)*duration);
    })(i);
}
```

So basically, the behavior is:

1. initialize (hide) all the paths
2. set them all to start after a duration*i delay

If the duration of a path drawing is already known, this should be easy to do.

Comment: thank you very much!!! i am trying with the dalay function but i couldnt make it!

Comment: window.setTimeout? >> 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: The trick also is to create a self invoked function, so the `i` parameter is inside a context (as it's passed as a parameter), and not modified by the outer `for`.

Comment: yes i will try to make self invoked function. thanks again for all.

Comment: hi! sorry for the disturbance but i have an internet explorer error. internet explorer debugger says "Unable to get property 'getTotalLength' of undefined or null reference". is there any way to get the length? so be compatible with the ie?